# gensim - Word2vec online training - AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'model_trimmed_post_training

Tags: nlp, word2vec, gensim

I am trying to use a pre-trained model and add additional vocabulary to it. I have a csv file with 1 column of sentences in it.

```
import gensim

existing_model_fr = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('./fr/fr.bin')

new_sentences = gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence('./data/french.csv')
existing_model_fr.build_vocab(new_sentences, update=True)

existing_model_fr.train(new_sentences, total_examples=existing_model_fr.corpus_count, epochs=5)
existing_model_fr.save('new_model_fr')
```

I get following error on existing_model_fr.train() line. What am I missing?

> AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) in ()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py in
>   train(self, sentences, total_examples, total_words, epochs,
>   start_alpha, end_alpha, word_count, queue_factor, report_delay,
>   compute_loss) 863 is only called once, the model's cached iter value
>   should be supplied as epochs value. 864 """ --> 865 if
>   self.model_trimmed_post_training: 866 raise RuntimeError("Parameters
>   for training were discarded using model_trimmed_post_training method")
>   867 if FAST_VERSION < 0:
>
> AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute
>   'model_trimmed_post_training'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you're loading a model from a earlier version of gensim where the property `model_trimmed_post_training` wasn't defined. You can likely work around the issue by setting the property yourself, after loading but before `train()`:

```
existing_model_fr. model_trimmed_post_training = false
```

Comment: Did following and it worked...
existing_model_fr.model_trimmed_post_training = False
existing_model_fr.compute_loss = False